# apollo client cache for nested queries

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a nested query (query inside query) with apollo client.
Everything works great, I do the request and get the correct data, but the issue is when I'm trying to use the cache, the cache returns `undefined` for the nested query prop.

My query:

```
query GetStudents($first: Int!, $after: String) {
  me {
    id
    email
    firstName
    lastName
    students(first: $first, after: $after) {
      edges {
        node {
            id
            created
            number
            status
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to use the inMemoryCache, the students is always `undefined` :

```
new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          me: {
            keyArgs: false,
            merge(existing = {}, incoming = {}, { readField }) {
              const id = readField("id", incoming);
              const email = readField("email", incoming);
              const students = readField("students", incoming);

              return {
                ...
              };
            },
          },
        }
      }
    }
});
```

I can read correctly the id and email from the cache, but the students (which is the nested query) will be always `undefined`.
Do I need to read the cache `students` in a different way because it is a query?